# Delphi : How to use Format() with runtime-built array of TVarRec?

Tags: delphi, pointers, string-formatting

I am building a SQL query builder for a repository. This builder will find all required fields for a query and create the SQL text. For this, I am using the Format() procedure. But, I am having trouble creating in runtime the TVarRec array that I must pass to the Format procedure.

It's easy to build this array using constants like Format('%s, %s', ['AString', 'AnotherString']);`. But how must we do to create it in runtime ?

Here is a simplified version of my approach :

```
procedure BuildString;
begin

    FStrings := TStringList.Create;

    FStrings.Add('String 1');
    FStrings.Add('String 2');
    FStrings.Add('String 3');

    FFormatString := '%0:s, %1:s, %2:s';

    SetLength(FFormatStringParams, FStrings.Count);

    for I := 0 to FStrings.Count - 1 do
    begin
      aString := FStrings.Strings[I];
      FFormatStringParams[I].VString := Addr(aString);
    end;

    ShowMessage(Format(FFormatString, FFormatStringParams));

end;
```

But when I run this, I get the error "The format '%0:s, %1:s, %2:s' is invalid or incompatible with the argument'

I understand that I am incorrectly building the TVarRec array that I must pass to the Format procedure. Can anyone help me in this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing the address of the string variable rather than its value. Furthermore, you are assigning the `VString` field, which expects a `ShortString`. You are supplying a native `String` instead.

Replace

```
VString := Addr(aString)
```

with

```
VUnicodeString := Pointer(aString)
```

Furthermore, you need to specify the string type by assigning the `VType` field.

```
for I := 0 to FStrings.Count - 1 do
begin
  aString := FStrings.Strings[I];
  FFormatStringParams[I].VType := vtUnicodeString;
  FFormatStringParams[I].VUnicodeString := Pointer(aString);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it!

Comment: FWIW, @Ludo, if you really want to manipulate `TVarRec`s, read my article about [open array parameters and array of const](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html). It also shows code that helps you do this.